# using a node to select a grandparent to select one of it's descendents

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have a tree similar to this:

```
         tr
        _|_
       td  td
      _|    |_
     div     div
     _|       |_ 
 input       "foobar"
```

I have the node "foobar' selected using:

```
//*[normalize-space(text())='foobar']
```

But I am unable to select the great grandparent `tr` and select great grand child `input` with it. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an exhaustive set of XPath expressions that you can use. :)

Comment: Exactly wat I was looking for. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the node "foobar' selected
>   using:
>
> ```
> //*[normalize-space(text())='foobar']
> ```
>
> But I am unable to select the great
>   grandparent tr and select great grand
>   child "foobar" with it.

I guess that you want to select the element whose string value (after normalization) is "foobar", starting from the top element `tr`.

Here is one XPath expression that "starts" from the top elemet `tr` and selects the wanted element:

```
/tr//*[normalize-space()='foobar']
```

If you need to select the text node itself (not its element parent):

```
/tr//text()[normalize-space()='foobar']
```

If you want to avoid the costly and slow evaluation of the `//` abbreviation (because you know the document structure), use this expression:

```
/tr/td/div[normalize-space()='foobar']
```

or even:

```
/tr/td[2]/div
```

**Update**:

Now the OP changed his question and wants to select the `input` element from the `div` that has normalized string-value 'foobar'.

**Here is an XPath expression selecting exactly this**:

```
../..//input
```

or

```
../../td[1]/div/input
```

**Do note**: In case these expressions don't select any node, it is most likely that the document has a default namespace -- search for XPath default namespace -- there are many good answers to this problem -- here at SO and on the internet.

Comment: i actually wrote it down wrong in the beginning. i have the foobar text node, i want to access the input living in the same tr parent. i edited my question above.

Comment: Nicely explained Dimitre. It helped. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression select every **element** having a **descendant text node** equal to "foobar" after whitespace normalization:

```
//*[.//text()[normalize-space()='foobar']]
```